# How to change add read write permissions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions

I have newly installed Windows 8.1 on a new miniDesktop:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Model** | Lenovo ThinkCentre |
| **CPU** | Intel® Core™ i5-4570T @ 2.90GHz × 4 |
| **RAM** | 3.7 GiB |
| **Disk** | 32.9 GB |

I dual booted it with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Problem is that I am not able to add write permissions to my Windows partitions. I have tried:

```
sudo chmod -wrx /media/pmay3/Data
```

All it returns with is

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/media/pmay3/Data': Read-only file system
```

Even if the folders are accessed from the graphical interface, and changing their permissions is attempted, it is
Screenshot of Permissions Tab:
[image]
Share your expertise please. I have re-installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and 18.04 LTS twice.

Comment: Is “Fast Boot” disabled? If not, the NTFS partitions appear too be in an open state, preventing any OS from being able to *safely* make changes to that data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows 10 partition; it "is in an unsafe state"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state) and [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/q/145902/)

Answer (score 1):

Common issue. Your ntfs volume probably is not "clean", i.e., it has not been properly closed. That is commonly the case if, in Windows, you have fastboot enabled. Part of the measures used to speed up shutting down and booting up is that the file system is not fully closed. Not a problem for Windows because it is designed to work that way, but to another operating system, the file system appears faulty. By default, Ubuntu will mount such file system read only.

Resolution

- Boot into Windows
- In Windows, disable fast start.
- Fully shut down Windows (i.e., no "sleep" or "hibernate" but a full close down).

In the future, you always need to have Windows fully shut down before you access the drive in Ubuntu. In Windows, have the drive now and then checked using the Windows disk checking tools.